# sed Invalid preceding regular expression when trying to use capturing group on a search and replace

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file that contains output from `s3bin sync` in a format as follows

```
Sync: s3://my-bin-url/source/000/000/001.jpg -> s3://my-bin-url/400/x/000/000/001.jpg
Sync: s3://my-bin-url/source/000/000/002.jpg -> s3://my-bin-url/400/x/000/000/002.jpg
Sync: s3://my-bin-url/source/000/000/003.jpg -> s3://my-bin-url/400/x/000/000/003.jpg
```

I wish to end up with a file containing the following

```
000/000/001.jpg
000/000/002.jpg
000/000/003.jpg
```

I am trying to do this using `sed` using the following command.  This is contained within a `#!/bin/sh` script, and `$2` corresponds to an absolute file path.  This file always exists.

```
sed --in-place --regexp-extended '/.*((?:[0-9]{3}\/){2}[0-9]{3}\.jpg)/\1/gi' $2
```

When I execute the script, I am getting the following error message

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 36: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Attempts to look up this issue have not yielded any useful responses so far, only suggestions revolve around ensuring the `/` is escaped (which it is) and escaping the `{}` (which only seems to apply when not using `--regexp-extended`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sed command is probably missing `s` command at the start.

Also you can use alternate regex delimiter in reg and avoid escaping `/`.

This sed should work:

```
sed -i -r 's#.*(([0-9]{3}/){2}[0-9]{3}\.jpg)#\1#i' file
```

Comment: I had tried changing from `/` to `#` to no avail earlier.  It's the removal of `g` from the `/gi` and the addition of a preceeding `s` that fixed it.  Thanks.  Settled on `s/.*(([0-9]{3}\/){2}[0-9]{3}\.jpg)/\1/i` (I know your version doesn't need the / escaping, but there you go)

Comment: You can put the `g` back but that's not needed since this sed is substituting only one per line. And yes `sed -r 's/.*(([0-9]{3}\/){2}[0-9]{3}\.jpg)/\1/i' file` will also work.

Comment: Not really needed, the `g` does work as you say.  Just before I posted this I added in the `-r` (so that fixed the curly braces issue), I guess I just hadn't tried `s/` with `-r` etc!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract those filenames but not over-write the file, you can use grep:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\+/[0-9]\+/[0-9]\+\.jpg$' filename
grep -oP '\d+/\d+/\d+\.jpg$' filename
```

Comment: The intention is to overwrite the file, I've no need of the unsanitised file in this instance